# Loading different js file in different themes in wordpress customizer api

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my Customizer Api in Wordpress, i have two radio buttons. I have two themes. All files are same on those two themes but few javascript files are different. Suppose, When i will select `Theme One`, I want to to load the whole template files and `theme-one.js` file, in this time,`theme-two.js` will not be loaded . Again , when I will select `Theme Two`, i want to load the whole template and `theme-two.js` file. In this time, `theme-one.js` will not be loaded.

My goal is to select themes in customize api and want to see the changed theme on the live preview.

what can i do?

Comment: Can you paste the code that you are using to create the two radio buttons at customizer?